# How to change a file's path within ruby

Tags: ruby, path, pathname

I'm trying to move files from one folder to another via Ruby, but I'm stuck trying to get Pathname.new to work. For reference the files are being held in array as an inbetween from their normal dir. I know I could move it via CLI but I'd like the program to do it for me.  This is what I have so far. I know it's wrong; I just don't get how to fix it.

```
temp_array.each {|song| song.path(Pathname.new("/Users/tsiege/Desktop/#{playlist_name}"))}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [FileUtils.mv](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv):

```
require 'fileutils'

temp_array.each do |song|
  FileUtils.mv song.path, "/Users/tsiege/Desktop/#{playlist_name}"
end
```

Be sure that the directory `#{playlist_name}` exists before you do, though:

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p "/Users/tsiege/Desktop/#{playlist_name}"
```

Comment: Should I put the require at the top of the program or does that not matter? I do have the directory set up, but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you only need the require statement before you use `FileUtils`, but putting it at the top is the convention.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for your help.  If I was allowed to upvote your answer I would.

Comment: Probably better to use `FileUtils.mkdir_p` because it will also create any intermediate files e.g. `a/b/c` where only `a` exists, `mkdir` will fail, because there is no `b` directory for it to put `c` into, but `mkdir_p` will just make the b directory first.

Answer (score 1):

To move files you can use `FileUtils.mv`:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mv 'from.ext', 'to.ext'
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv

And if you want a list of files in a directory you can use:

```
Dir['/path/to/dir/*']
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html

Lastly, you may also want to check if you have a file or directory:

```
File.file? file
File.directory? dir
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-file-3F